# Is this contradiction proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Statement : suppose $a,b$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$ (integers). If $4/ (a^2 + b^2)$ then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd.

Proof by contradiction:
Assume that if $4/(a^2 + b^2)$ then a and b are both odd.

If $a^2$ and $b^2$ is odd then by definition a and b must be odd too.

It follows that $a^2$ (or $b^2$) $= (4k+1)^2$  -----  (unsure about this step)

Then a (or b) $= 4k+1$  ---- (unsure about this step)

So if $a$ and $b$ are both odd then this is a contradiction hence the supposition is false and the statement is true.

Comment: Are you trying to say, if $\frac{4}{a^2+b^2} \in \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: If you want to prove "If A then B" by contradiction, then you should start with: "Suppose by contradiction that we have A and not B."  So, in your case, we should start with: "Assume by contradiction that $4|(a^2+b^2)$ and $a$ and $b$ are both odd."  Then see if you can derive a contradiction.  Starting with "Assume that if A then not B" won't help you to prove your original claim because it's not the negation of the original claim.

Additionally, an odd number can be written as $2k+1$ for some integer $k$, but it can't necessarily be written as $4k+1$.  So you may need to rethink those steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof by contradiction should start with

> assume that $a$ and $b$ are both odd and $4\mid (a^2+b^2)$

You can continue by saying

> write $a=2h+1$ and $b=2k+1$

and

> so that $a^2+b^2=4h^2+4h+1+4k^2+4k+1=\dots$

Now you can add

> and we have a contradiction, because this would imply $\dots$

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4\implies a^2\equiv0,1$

Observe that  unless both $a,b\equiv0\pmod2,$ i.e., both $a,b\equiv0,2\pmod4$

$a^2+b^2\not\equiv0\pmod4$

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by this step: a≡±0,1,2(mod4)?

Comment: @joe, What are the possible moduli of any integer $\pmod4$?